# SQL Concatenate Rows by Composite Group

Tags: sql, db2, recursive-query, db2-luw

I need to concatenate rows values into a column based on which group the row belongs to using two grouping values.

**TBL1**

```
    cat1 cat2 cat3 value
    ---- ---- ---- -----
    1    1    lvl1 100
    1    2    lvl2 abc 
    1    3    lvl2 cba 
    2    1    lvl1 200 
    2    2    lvl2 abb
    3    1    lvl1 100
    3    2    lvl2 bbc
    3    3    lvl2 acc
    3    4    lvl1 400
    3    5    lvl2 acc 
    4    1    lvl1 300
    4    2    lvl2 aab
    ...
```

**TBL2**

```
    cat1 cat2 value
    ---- ---- ---------
    1    100  abc, cba
    2    200  abb
    3    100  bbc, aac
    3    400  aac
    4    300  aab
    ...
```

This is using static DB2 SQL. The actual table has over a thousand records.

Comment: What DB2 version and platform?

Comment: DBMS_Ver - 11.01.0005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least some versions of DB2 support `listagg()`.  So the tricky part is identifying the groups.  You can do this by counting the number of rows with where the value is a number, cumulatively.  The resulting query is something like this:

```
select cat1,
       max(case when value >= '0' and value <= '999' then value end) as cat2,
       listagg(case when not value >= '0' and value <= '999' then value end, ', ') within group (order by cat2) as value
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when value >= '0' and value <= '999' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by cat1, cat2) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by cat1, grp;
```

Checking for a number in DB2 can be tricky.  The above uses simple between logic that is sufficient for your sample data.

Comment: I've no idea how you understood what he was asking.

Comment: @Hogan . . . One of the two most important things that I learn from this site is how to  understand what other people are asking -- at least in this very limited technical domain.